# Can you help me on file.encrypt?

Tags: c#, console

I would like to encrypt and decrypt files but this shows me an error "This request is not supported" and "Invalid descriptor".
Can you help me ?

I have two methods AddEncryption and RemoveEncryption which encrypts and decrypts the file passed in FileName.

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        string FileName = "C:\Users\PORTABLEHP\Documents\a.txt";
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypt" + FileName);
        AddEncryption(FileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt" + FileName);
        RemoveEncryption(FileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void AddEncryption(string FileName)
{
    File.Encrypt(FileName);
}

public static void RemoveEncryption(string FileName)
{
    File.Decrypt(FileName);
}
```

Comment: probably you want to use double slashes inside of string, ie `"c:\\Users...";`

Comment: No , i write @"C:\...

Comment: The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netframework-4.8) explains a lot about this error. Are you running this program on a non NTFS file system?

Comment: Yes, okay i know !

Comment: What is my problem ? My files system it's under NTFS!

Comment: Which o/s are you using?

Comment: I'm under windows 8.1 Home édition

Comment: That's the problem. Please have a look at limitation mentioned as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation of `File.Encrypt` method has been described at [File.Encrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=netframework-4.8)

> **Important**
>
> This API is only supported on Windows platforms that are able to use
>   the ***NTFS*** Encrypting File System (EFS). ***Any attempt to use this on
>   non-Windows systems, Windows Home Edition systems, or non-NTFS drives
>   results in a PlatformNotSupportedException or NotSupportedException,
>   depending on the situation***.
>
> Use of this API in .NET Core is not recommended; it is included to
>   enable portability for applications that move to .NET Core but still
>   explicitly target Windows.